# plink unable to execute the command with parameters

Tags: plink

i could not able to execute the command with parameters in the plink.exe, when i provide the parameter command 'ls', it executes perfectly.

but if i provide command with parameters let's say 'ls -ltr', it say's commmand not found, this command executes perfectly in the unix command shell.

### source code

```
c:\Gopal\putty>PLINK.exe -ssh gopc@hyperlvs03.qa.paypal.com -i c:\gopal\putty\gopc-private-key.ppk 'ls'
5036
BR-SWAT
CustomerOnBoardingEmailDataVO.oml~
GOPC.PG.conf
GOPC.PG.log
GOPC2.PG.conf
GOPC2.PG.log
GOPC2_PG.py
GOPC2_PG.pyc
GOPC_PG.py
GOPC_PG.pyc
GTest
Mail
\
afiedt.buf
color.sh
color.txt
compile.ksh
compile.ksh.bkup
error_log
file_backup_script.ksh
file_comp.txt
file_comp.txt_dev_BR_SWAT_38350
file_comp.txt_webdev_BR_SWAT_38350
file_not_found.txt
files_diff.txt
files_diff_compare.sh
gimp
gopc-0af4ba41-7528-20110810-211015190-cc_confirm.confirm_cc.vo.req.xml
i686
logs
mm-logs
mycommit
oradiag_UNKNOWN
oradiag_gopc
projects
public_html
scratch
scripts
stage.txt
tr
web.log

c:\Gopal\putty>PLINK.exe -ssh gopc@hyperlvs03.qa.paypal.com -i c:\gopal\putty\gopc-private-key.ppk 'ls -ltr'
bash: ls -ltr: command not found
```

please find the screen shot for the reference.

Comment: can you try removing '' from ls-ltr and check

Comment: thanks very much double quotes is executing